# Grouping in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a calendar and I want to group this data..so I have this in my controller

```
  @entry_by_date = Entry.where("emp_mail_addr = ? and emp_first_name = ? and  emp_last_name = ? and emp_dept = ?", current_user.email, current_user.emp_first_name, current_user.emp_last_name, current_user.emp_dept).group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date}
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
```

Question is for @entry_by_date I have it .group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date} 
how can I make this have group by two dates for example....

@entry_by_date........group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date} {|i| i.leave_end.to_date}

So it will now group by leave_start and leave_end so now on my calendar it will show up with leave start and leave end dates..

I tried doing it like this

```
 @entry_by_date = Entry.where("emp_mail_addr = ? and emp_first_name = ? and  emp_last_name = ? and emp_dept = ?", current_user.email, current_user.emp_first_name, current_user.emp_last_name, current_user.emp_dept).group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date}
 @entry_by_date = Entry.where("emp_mail_addr = ? and emp_first_name = ? and  emp_last_name = ? and emp_dept = ?", current_user.email, current_user.emp_first_name, current_user.emp_last_name, current_user.emp_dept).group_by {|i| i.leave_end.to_date}
```

but only leave start showed up or if I switched them leave end would show up. I would like for both to show up and suggestions are greatly appreciated!!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Be aware that there is a critical difference between [`group_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) and [`group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) APIs - the former works on lists (*after* they have been fetched from the database), while the latter is used in the database query itself (adding it a `GROUP BY` clause)
2. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to have the keys of your group to be an array of dates, you could do it in a single `group_by` block:

   ```
   @entry_by_date = entries.group_by { |i| [i.leave_start.to_date, i.leave_end.to_date] }
   ```

   If you want each entry to be grouped *twice* (once with its start date, and once with its end date), you need to create 2 grouped maps, and *join* them:

   ```
   entry_by_start_date = entries.group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date}
   entry_by_end_date = entries.group_by {|i| i.leave_end.to_date}
   @entry_by_date = entry_by_start_date.merge(entry_by_end_date) {|key, oldval, newval| newval + oldval}
   ```

Comment: I tried this @entry_by_date = entries.group_by { |i| [i.leave_start.to_date, i.leave_end.to_date] } and no data came up..

Comment: @user3910236 - what do you mean nothing came up? you understand that `entries` is a shorthand for your `Entry.where("...")`

Comment: Nevermind lol!!! forgot to cap the E in entry....sorry!!! thanks this solved my problem!!!